# Land e Portrait

Tags: android

Como ficaria o código da imagem, para que mantenha as proporções de distância entre as views tanto em landscape como portrait? A imagem abaixo é só protótipo não tem código ainda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim "Código da imagem"? E que proporções seriam essas? Exemplifique melhor sua dúvida, coloque o protótipo da versão em modo paisagem e use números, se possível. Se você fizer o código pelo menos da versão retrato, vai ajudar bastante.

Comment: Acredito que usar o ConstraintLayout vai te auxiliar na sua necessidade, segue o link explicando como utiliza-lo. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Código da imagem: XML do layout apresentado. Proporções de distâncias: margens entre os componentes.

Comment: Não sei se isso será um comentário repetitivo, mas, como o Pablo Almeida insinuou você pode fazer um layout para a versão landscape e um para a portrait. Tendo já o arquivo da layout, clique com o botão direito na pasta layout do res > New > Layout resource file, nessa janela em "Available qualifiers" selecione "Orientation e clique na seta dupla para a direita, escolha "Landscape" e crie o arquivo com o mesmo nome do que você já tinha. O AndroidStudio criará um novo arquivo XML onde você poderá fazer seu layout em landscape, e ao recriar o layout girando o smartphone, aparecerá o adequado

Comment: Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver o caso. Era apenas uma questão de alinhamento entre um componente e outro.